# Why is the word "Kotveinu" not "Kotbeinu" with a dagesh?

Tags: grammar-dikduk

כתבינו לחיים.
The tav has a (seemingly) short vowel to close the first vowel, which sefardim pronounce as the short "kot".
There is no meteg before the sh'va of the tav.
Why is the bet written without a dagesh kal?

Note: This is unrelated to the discussion on how to pronounce a vet (some sefardim say "b" even without a dagesh). Even so, here it appears without a dagesh.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/78905/why-is-the-second-kaf-hard-in-%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%99-%D7%9B%D7%9C-%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56433/why-not-%D7%A4%D6%B4%D6%BC%D7%98%D6%B0%D7%93%D6%B8%D6%BC%D6%BD%D7%94